# How to create (TOC) table of content and add it after merging multiple pdf reports together in one pdf

Tags: java, jasper-reports, itext

I've concatenated multiple reports using the Batch export mode (JRPdfExporter and JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT_LIST).Now, I'm trying to create the TOC (table of contents) for my report. Is there a way to make references or indexes that reference to titles and sub-titles on my report (multiple levels of titles)?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/tableofcontents/index.html)?

Comment: If the documents don't have any structure, it is not trivial to do this. This is explained here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lZnbhnU4m3Y You should create your initial documents with bookmarks and concatenate those bookmarks during the merge process, **not** after! In other words: your design is wrong; you are doing things in the wrong order. Rethink your process design.

Comment: @Payam yes i tried it, in my case the report page number begin by 1 for each concatenated report, to fix that, i've using pdfStamper.getoverContent (continuous numbers of pages) so I can't used it now because I haven't the right number of pages of currents pages during the genration. thanks

Comment: thanks for reply, @BrunoLowagie you're right I'm doing things in the wrong order, I should watch the video, but just a question plz, what if I use Itext instead of JRPDFexporter (JASPER) to conactenate the  pdfs, can I realize the bookmarks and cancatenate it?

Comment: That is explained in chapter 7 of my book, more specifically where I explain the ConcatenateBookmarks example: http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=141 This, of course, assumes that the original documents have bookmarks.

Comment: thank you @BrunoLowagie, my reports are generated using jasperreports, should I regenerate it using IText? or can I add the bookmarks on the jrxml file and then I'll concatenate them during the merge process? I'm asking this question because I didn't use IText from the begin, I used jrxml/Jasper file.

Comment: I don't know JasperReports well enough, but as far as I understand the link provided by @Payam, I think you can create PDFs with bookmarks from JasperReports. Ask the question to the JasperReports community for confirmation.